# Displaying Wordpress Blog Post on Non-Wordpress Page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I've tried searching but can't find any clear answers.

I have a Wordpress site with some non-Wordpress (PHP) pages that are located in the root directory.

I'm trying to display the content from a WP post on one of these non-WP pages. Since the post is constantly updated, simply copy/pasting the content won't work.

I guess I could create a template with the non-WP content and just exclude the theme/header/footer... but I'd prefer to keep the file in the root directory with the other pages.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can use rest api and display the posts

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the rest api? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for you is providing an API for your Wordpress posts then use it in non-wordpress pages.

Also you can use the wordpress `REST-API`itself, it has provided so many useful capabilities.

Take a look at it:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/